# Selenium Capturescreenshot() not working in IE8

Tags: selenium

I have the following code in my C# program:

selenium.CaptureScreenshot("c:\test.png");

Unfortunately every time I run the program it falls over when I reach this line. I am running my tests on an IE8 browser. The error message i keep getting is shown below. Any help would be appreciated - i've tried everything and am on the verge of giving up. PS. I'm using selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0

Selenium.NotSupportedException: CaptureScreenshot

is there sometghing around CaptureScreenShiot not working in Internet Explorer 8

Comment: Try with a forward slash or with single quotes. I know it sounds silly but when I was using Ruby and the screenshot feature I had exactly the same issue like you. Not sure if the same thing goes for Java but try: selenium.CaptureScreenshot("c:/test.png"); and selenium.CaptureScreenshot('c:\test.png'); By the way have you managed to run the same in Firefox or Chrome? Does it still behave the same?